# AWS SES un-disclose recipients

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

Is it possible to hide the recipients (or other recipients) list from the emails that a user can receive from AWS SES? Is this a supported feature? Or should I really need to loop through an array of email addresses and send them one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your sake and privacy issues, I'd suggest you don't show in the same email the other recipients email addresses. So yes, you'd rather build your emails, one by one. Take a look at [MoonMail](http://github.com/microapps/MoonMail) which can be helpful. Disclaimer: I'm a contributor @moonmail

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the BCC addresses instead of the 'to' address to hide the list of recipients.